# WiX: управление записями в разделе реестра HKCU

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix

Делаю инсталлятор прораммы на WiX ([wixtoolset.org](http://wixtoolset.org/)).

Программа создает в ключе HKCU ключ со своими параметрами.

Как можно сделать, чтобы при деинсталляции удалялись все ключи программы из всех пользовательских ключей HKCU?

Answer (score 2):

Установщик должен удалять записи, которые он создает и ничего больше. Если ваше приложение создает для каждого пользователя настройки во время выполнения, то это не касается деинсталятора.
Если вы действительно очень хотите это сделать, вы можете создать пользовательские действия(CustomAction), что очень не рекомендуется, так как вы можете существенно повредить операционную систему.

Что то типа такого:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_UninstallRegistryCleanUp" Directory="SystemFolder" ExeCommand="REG.exe ADD &quot;HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\MySoftName_CleanUp&quot; /v StubPath /d &quot;reg add ^&quot;HKCU\Key\To\Be\Removed^&quot; /va /f&quot; /f" Return="ignore" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CA_UninstallRegistryCleanUp' After='RemoveRegistryValues'>REMOVE~="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Component Id='RegCleanup_Remover' Guid='*'>
  <RegistryValue Id="PerUserRegistry_KeyPAth" Root="HKLM" KeyPath="yes" Key="SOFTWARE\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\[ProductCode]\" Name="DummyKey" Value="[ProductVersion]" Type="string" />
  <RemoveRegistryKey Id='RegCleanup_Remover' Root='HKLM' Action='removeOnInstall' Key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\MySoftName_CleanUp'/>
</Component>
```

Comment: но у вас идет удаление из HKLM, а мне нужно удалять из HKCU каждого профиля, что есть на компьютере